# AngularJS, MVC4, Web API, Json Deserialize $ref

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-4, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

Through an HttpResponseMessage MVC4 successfully sends an AngularJs controller $scope of GetAllFolders().

**A Folder in the collection has among other things and association to the Photo class.**

**Folders can be folders of other folders (self-referencing).**

Debugging shows from MVC4 side all is good and correct detail information was returned.

But through Angular/Json, certain properties are $ref tag and can not be seen, as example:

[image]

I do not care much for creating a method call on FkPhotoId and hit the server for the image name when I know it was already sent in the first response.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE: SOLUTION**

This code was added in the global.asax: (make sure you reference it in the start method)

```
    public static void ConfigureApi(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        var json = config.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
        config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore; 
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Please add your solution as an answer -- then this question won't show up on the "unanswered" list.  You can (and should) also accept it.

Comment: how to go about doing that?

Comment: In the textbox below, type in your answer, click the "Post Your Answer" button.  (Optionally remove your solution from the question).  Then click the checkmark next to your answer.

Answer (score 8):

Resolution from OP (housecleaning - marking so can mark answered)
This code was added in the global.asax: (make sure you reference it in the start method)

```
public static void ConfigureApi(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    var json = config.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
    config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
    config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am tired of seeing this answer "Just disable stuff and work around it." It's lazy, it's wrong, and incredibly reductive to the usefulness of retaining this data.

This is a three part answer. The first part is to disable collection references and only retain objects.

In my case, I couldn't think of a scenario where I would be sharing collection references and the additional code is messy. If you need collection references WRITE THE CONSUMING FE LOGIC. Don't just disable it. It just happened that I didn't need it.

```C#
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Serialize;
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects;
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
```

The second portion is here. I got this from another answer and added a tweak that was missing. (This is the original [Resolve circular references from JSON object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15312529/resolve-circular-references-from-json-object)):

```js
function resolveReferences(json) {
    if (!json)
        return json;

    if (typeof json === 'string')
        json = JSON.parse(json);

    var byid = {}, // all objects by id
        refs = []; // references to objects that could not be resolved
    json = (function recurse(obj, prop, parent) {
        if (typeof obj !== 'object' || !obj) // a primitive value
            return obj;
        if (Object.prototype.toString.call(obj) === '[object Array]') {
            for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++)
                // check also if the array element is not a primitive value
                if (typeof obj[i] !== 'object' || !obj[i]) // a primitive value
                    continue;
                else if ("$ref" in obj[i])
                    obj[i] = recurse(obj[i], i, obj);
                else
                    obj[i] = recurse(obj[i], prop, obj);
            return obj;
        }
        if ("$ref" in obj) { // a reference
            var ref = obj.$ref;
            if (ref in byid)
                return byid[ref];
            // else we have to make it lazy:
            refs.push([parent, prop, ref]);
            return;
        } else if ("$id" in obj) {
            var id = obj.$id;
            delete obj.$id;
            if ("$values" in obj) // an array
                obj = obj.$values.map(recurse);
            else // a plain object
                for (var prop in obj)
                    obj[prop] = recurse(obj[prop], prop, obj);
            byid[id] = obj;
        }
        return obj;
    })(json); // run it!

    for (var i = 0; i < refs.length; i++) { // resolve previously unknown references
        var ref = refs[i];
        ref[0][ref[1]] = byid[ref[2]];
        // Notice that this throws if you put in a reference at top-level
    }
    return json;
}
```

The second portion is to reprocess and reestablish circular dependencies prior to sending the data back. My FE is an angular app, so I am personally calling this in an injected HTTP interceptor prior to the ajax posts.(note I am checking for a property called "typeName" because all objects with that property are assumed to be objects that will be deserialized on the back end).

```js
function processReferenceEstablishment(data) {
    if (!data || typeof (data) === 'function')
        return undefined;

    var processData = [];
    var tiers = {};
    var refKey = 1;
    if (Array.isArray(data)) {
        data = jQuery.extend([], data);
    } else {
        data = jQuery.extend({}, data);
    }


   

    var retVal = (function recurse(obj, tier) {
        tiers[tier] = tiers[tier] || {};
        tiers[tier].width = tiers[tier].width ? tiers[tier].width + 1 : 1;
        if (obj) {
            if (typeof obj !== 'object' || typeof (obj) === 'function') {
                return obj;
            }

            for (var key in data) {
                var val = data[key];
                if (key.indexOf("$") > -1 || typeof(val) === 'function') {
                    delete data[key];
                }
            }
            if (Array.isArray(obj)) {
                obj = jQuery.extend([], obj);
                for (var ix = 0; ix < obj.length; ix++) {
                    obj[ix] = recurse(obj[ix], tier);
                }
            }
            else if ('typeName' in obj) {
                if (obj.skipSend) {
                    return undefined;
                }
                obj = jQuery.extend({}, obj);
                var found = false;
                for (var pdIx = 0; pdIx < processData.length; pdIx++) {
                    var item = processData[pdIx];
                    if (item.id === obj.id && item.typeName === obj.typeName) {
                        found = true;
                        if (!item.jsonTier || item.jsonTier > tier) {
                            item.jsonTier = tier;
                            item.jsonWidth = tiers[tier].width;
                        }
                        if (tier === item.jsonTier && item.jsonWidth > tiers[tier].width) {
                            item.jsonWidth = tiers[tier].width;
                        }
                        if (tier > item.jsonTier || (tier === item.jsonTier && item.jsonWidth < tiers[tier].width)) {
                            return { $ref: item.$id.toString() };
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (!found) {
                    obj.$id = refKey;
                    refKey++;
                    processData.push({$id:obj.$id, id: obj.id, typeName: obj.typeName, jsonTier: tier, jsonWidth: tiers[tier].width });
                }
                var keys = Object.keys(obj);
                keys.sort();
                for (var key in keys) {
                    key = keys[key];
                    obj[key] = recurse(obj[key], tier + 1);
                }
            }
        }
        return obj;
    })(data, 1);

    retVal = (function recurse(obj, tier) {
        tiers[tier] = tiers[tier] || {};
        tiers[tier].destWidth = tiers[tier].destWidth ? tiers[tier].destWidth + 1 : 1;
        if (typeof obj !== 'object' || !obj) {
            return obj;
        }
        if (Array.isArray(obj)) {
            for (var ix = 0; ix < obj.length; ix++) {
                obj[ix] = recurse(obj[ix], tier);
            }
        }
        else if ('typeName' in obj) {
            var found = false;
            for (var pdIx = 0; pdIx < processData.length; pdIx++) {
                var item = processData[pdIx];
                if (item.id === obj.id && item.typeName === obj.typeName) {
                    found = true;
                    if (item.jsonTier < tier || (item.jsonTier === tier && item.jsonWidth < tiers[tier].destWidth)) {
                        return { $ref: item.id.toString() };
                    }
                }
            }
            var keys = Object.keys(obj);
            keys.sort();
            for (var key in keys) {
                key = keys[key];
                obj[key] = recurse(obj[key], tier + 1);
            }
        }
        return obj;
    })(retVal, 1);
    return retVal;
}
```

Now, to be clear. My reestablishment of $ref and $id is often happening out of order and I get the odd collection object reference or navigation property object reference on the back end that comes back null. I am still working on that. I really need to pull down the NewtonSoft.JSON libraries and pull them apart to figure out what order to process the object graph in so I can eliminate the null references after deserialization.

To me, this is headed for a real solution instead of throwing in the towel and disabling circular references because of laziness.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add my two cents. I had this extra line in my code that was also causing this issue

```
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects;
```

Thanks digger69 for this one.