# EF Lazy Loading is Disable, But Still EF Loads Full Graph

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lazy-loading

I have disabled lazy loading of EF 6.1 using the following code

```
public MyContext() : base("DefaultConnection")
{
    this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
    this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
}
```

Then I load my object using the following line.

```
T result = (T)context.Set<T>().Find(id);
```

Where T is an object in my domain that has some navigation properties. I am expecting this `Find` method to return the object without the navigation properties since I have disabled lazy loading, but when I run my code and check the variable values I find that the navigation properties were loaded too! Anybody knows what the problem might be?

**EDIT**

Here is a mini sample

**MyContext**

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{

    public MyContext() : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
        this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
    }

    public DbSet<Lesson> Lessons { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Part> Parts { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

}
```

**Model**

```
public class Lesson
{

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Part Part { get; set; }

}


public class Part
{

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

**Client Code**

```
            using (MyContext c = new EFTest.MyContext())
            {

                Lesson d = new EFTest.Lesson();
                d.Part = new EFTest.Part() { Name = "a" };

                Lessson insert = c.Lessons.Add(d);
                c.SaveChanges();

                Lesson returned = c.Lessons.Find(insert.Id);
            }
```

Comment: EF:   Core or  Not Core ?  Version?

Comment: Entity Framework  6.1

Comment: Sounds strange, show us a [mcve], and/or the genrated sql.

Comment: Also, which provider?

Comment: SqlClient provider

Comment: see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31978388/60761). Did you load any of the nav property data beforehand?

Comment: Though, adding a full sample here is very hard, the system has lots of moving part.

Comment: An mcve calls for a _minimal_ sample. Often a good way to find the answer yourself.

Comment: I have added a sample above, I am suspecting that the Find method is getting the object from cache, where the full graph is already cached, what do you think?

Comment: @Sisyphus Indeed `Find` is taking the object from cache if it is there, from db otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out that the problem was with my client code. When I try to find an object I have just inserted EF gets it from its cache where it already exists with the full graph, so the full graph is returned. But when I tried to Find(1) instead of Find(Insert.Id) it returned a shallow object correctly. Also using the AsNoTracking method on the DbSet yielded the same result.