# Self referencing loop detected for property asp.net web api

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I'm receiving an infinite loop error when accessing the get method for my contact object. I'm accessing a data model that has been in use in other projects extensively and I believe it is not the problem.

Please let me know if additional info would help.

I'm accessing the getContacts via the url http://localhost:65207/Api/contacts

This is the method

```
return db.contacts.Include(c => c.businesscontacts);
```

The query returns succesfully if I apply take(1)

```
return db.contacts.Take(1).Include(c => c.businesscontacts);
```

And the stack trace

> {"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"The
>   'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for
>   content type 'text/html;
>   charset=utf-8'.","ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException","StackTrace":null,"InnerException":{"Message":"An
>   error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"Self referencing loop
>   detected for property 'contact' with type
>   'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.contact_86EA38F6B924D1435BCF3A7E50D07D29E0003280D2026E3A4AF9F36C87F1F214'.
>   Path
>   '[1].businesscontacts[0]'.","ExceptionType":"Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException","StackTrace":"
>   at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.CheckForCircularReference(JsonWriter
>   writer, Object value, JsonProperty property, JsonContract contract,
>   JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty
>   containerProperty)\r\n at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.CalculatePropertyValues(JsonWriter
>   writer, Object value, JsonContainerContract contract, JsonProperty
>   member, JsonProperty property, JsonContract& memberContract, Object&
>   memberValue)\r\n at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter
>   writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty
>   member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty
>   containerProperty)\r\n at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter
>   writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member,
>   JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty
>   containerProperty)\r\n at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeList(JsonWriter
>   writer, IEnumerable values, JsonArrayContract contract, JsonProperty
>   member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty
>   containerProperty)\r\n at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter
>   writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member,
>   JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty
>   containerProperty)\r\n at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter
>   writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty
>   member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty
>   containerProperty)\r\n at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter
>   writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member,
>   JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty
>   containerProperty)\r\n at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeList(JsonWriter
>   writer, IEnumerable values, JsonArrayContract contract, JsonProperty
>   member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty
>   containerProperty)\r\n at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter
>   writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member,
>   JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty
>   containerProperty)\r\n at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.Serialize(JsonWriter
>   jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType)\r\n at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.SerializeInternal(JsonWriter
>   jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType)\r\n at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object
>   value)\r\n at
>   System.Net.Http.Formatting.BaseJsonMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStream(Type
>   type, Object value, Stream writeStream, Encoding
>   effectiveEncoding)\r\n at
>   System.Net.Http.Formatting.JsonMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStream(Type
>   type, Object value, Stream writeStream, Encoding
>   effectiveEncoding)\r\n at
>   System.Net.Http.Formatting.BaseJsonMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStream(Type
>   type, Object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content)\r\n at
>   System.Net.Http.Formatting.BaseJsonMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStreamAsync(Type
>   type, Object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content,
>   TransportContext transportContext, CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken)\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location
>   where exception was thrown ---\r\n at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()\r\n at
>   System.Web.Http.WebHost.HttpControllerHandler.d__1b.MoveNext()"}}

Answer (score 1):

Quite likely the problem is that some BusinessContacts contains reference to Contacts... and then you end up with circular reference that just jumps between BusinessContacts and Contacts.

Take a look at this question for additional info:

[How Do You "Really" Serialize Circular Referencing Objects With Newtonsoft.Json?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26434738/how-do-you-really-serialize-circular-referencing-objects-with-newtonsoft-json)