# Angular 4.3 HttpClient : Intercept response

Tags: javascript, angular, http, interceptor

In the documentation about the new `HttpClientModule` included in the new version of Angular 4.3, the mechanism to intercept requests is explained very well. There is also mention of the response interceptor mechanism however I cannot find anything about it.

Does anyone have an idea about how to intercept a response in order to modify the body message before it is sent to the service?

Thanks.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Since Angular 6 release, RxJs 6.0 changed its interface, so you cannot use operators the same way (like `.map()`, `.tap()`...).
Because of that, most of the above solutions are outdated.
This is how you correctly modify content of an Observable using RxJs 6.0+ (with `pipe`):

```
import {HttpEvent, HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest, HttpResponse} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
import {map} from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable()
export class ResponseInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    intercept(req: HttpRequest, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

        return next.handle(req).pipe(map((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
            if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
                event = event.clone({body: this.modifyBody(event.body)});
            }
            return event;
        }));

    }

    private modifyBody(body: any) {
        /*
        * write your logic to modify the body
        * */
    }
}
```

Comment: Had to use `HttpEvent<any>` then it worked in Angular 6! Thanks!

Comment: Sorry my bad.. had code had a typo, just updated the answer

Comment: No no, the response type `Observable<HttpEvent<any>>` was correct, but in `return next.handle(req).pipe(tap((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {} ` I have to use `HttpEvent<any>`

Comment: This didn't work for me. Using `tap` didn't preserve the actual modified body I was creating. I changed it to `map` and that worked instead.

Comment: On Angular 10 it needs to be `req: HttpRequest<any>`

Answer (score 66):

I recently made an `HttpInterceptor` in order to resolve cyclical references in some JSON on the client side, essentially replacing any object with a `$ref` property with the object in the JSON that has a matching `$id` property. (This is the output you get if Json.Net is configured with `PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects` and `ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore`).

The answers here helped me some of way, but none of them show how to modify the body of the response, like the OP needs. In order to do so, one needs to clone the event and update the body, like so:

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(req).map(event => {
        if (event instanceof HttpResponse && shouldBeIntercepted(event)) {
            event = event.clone({ body: resolveReferences(event.body) })
        }         
        return event;
    });
}
```

Any event that should not be modified is simply passed through to the next handler.

Comment: ^^ The only answer that actually shows how to modify response, worked for me in Angular 5.2.4 typescript 2.6.2

Comment: I was looking for this too, and now I realize it is the same as changing the request: `request = request.clone({ url: 'new-url' })`. Very useful

Comment: If you came here in 2019 - pipe also needed:

`import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';`

`next.handle(clonedRequest).pipe(map(event => { ... }))`

Comment: Works perfectly with @DmitryGusarov's change. If specifically trying to solve the same problem with JSON.net $ref/$id, I used this for resolving the references: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21686499/how-to-restore-circular-references-e-g-id-from-json-net-serialized-json

Comment: but what if i wish to interrupt the interceptor chain if in response there is something wrong?

Comment: Is it necessary to clone and return event? Can we directly send the event.body?

Answer (score 59):

I suppose you can use `do` as @federico-scamuzzi suggested, or you can use `map` and `catch` like so:

```typescript
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
  HttpErrorResponse,
  HttpEvent,
  HttpHandler,
  HttpInterceptor,
  HttpRequest,
  HttpResponse
} from '@angular/common/http';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';

@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    console.info('req.headers =', req.headers, ';');
    return next.handle(req)
      .map((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
        if (event instanceof HttpResponse && ~~(event.status / 100) > 3) {
          console.info('HttpResponse::event =', event, ';');
        } else console.info('event =', event, ';');
        return event;
      })
      .catch((err: any, caught) => {
        if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
          if (err.status === 403) {
            console.info('err.error =', err.error, ';');
          }
          return Observable.throw(err);
        }
      });
  }
}
```

---

EDIT: @LalitKushwah was asking about redirecting `if(!loggedIn)`. I use [Route Guards](https://angular.io/guide/router#guards), specifically:

```typescript
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRouteSnapshot, CanActivate, Router, RouterStateSnapshot
       } from '@angular/router';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

import { AuthService } from '../../api/auth/auth.service';
import { AlertsService } from '../alerts/alerts.service';

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private router: Router,
              private alertsService: AlertsService) {}

  canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
              state: RouterStateSnapshot
              ): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    if (AuthService.loggedIn()) return true;

    const url: string = state.url;

    this.alertsService.add(`Auth required to view ${url}`);
    this.router
      .navigate(['/auth'], { queryParams: { redirectUrl: url } })
      .then(() => {});
    return false;
  }
}
```

Then I can simply add that as an argument to my route:

```js
{
  path: 'dashboard', loadChildren:'app/dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule',
  canActivate: [AuthGuard]
}
```

EDIT: As of [Angular 15 released Nov 2022](https://blog.angular.io/angular-v15-is-now-available-df7be7f2f4c8) you can use this functional pattern:

```typescript
const route = {
  path: 'admin',
  canActivate: [() => inject(LoginService).isLoggedIn()]
};
```

Comment: you're my hero. hope one day you'll receive an oscar!

Comment: Can you please explain `~(event.status / 100) > 3`?

Comment: If it's a 400 or 500 HTTP error then that condition will be true. `~` deals with str->num conversion—in this context—better than `+`.

Comment: Can we use NavController in interceptor while intercepting response? The scenario is if I got 'loggedIn false' in response so I want to redirect user to Login page.

Comment: @LalitKushwah I have updated my answer to resolve your query.

Comment: @RoyiNamir: Whoops, missing my second `~` there. Good find. Edited.

Comment: Do you provide this injectable as an service inside your app module?

Comment: But isn't HttpResponse status property already a number? At least it seems so with angular 5.2.2

Comment: [`HttpResponse['status']`](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpResponseBase#status) is indeed a `number`. But dividing it by `100` could leave a decimal, I want whole non-negative numbers (`unsigned int` in C). Because I want a `301` response code to be truthy. `3.01` is greater than `3`.

Comment: Small remark: to get only responses **with a body**, instead of checking for `instanceof` you may use `event.type === HttpEventType.Response` (enum is exposed in  `@angular/common/http` module).

Comment: Since event.status is already number would this not suffice:

if(event.status >= 400)?

It feel like that's much easier to read and does the same thing.

Comment: One question. How can i get data from a promise and append it to req.clone?

Answer (score 6):

From what i can understand (I've only done the intercept for request and inject auth token) .. you can attach a .do() and test if is a reponse .. like (as doc says):

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';

export class TimingInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private auth: AuthService) {}

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const started = Date.now();
    return next
      .handle(req)
      .do(event => {
        if (event instanceof HttpResponse) { //<-- HERE
          const elapsed = Date.now() - started;
          console.log(event} ms.`);
        }
      });
  }

}
```

Comment: the .do(...) doesn't return the event right? unlike the map example as @A T have cited as an example below.