# How to read respose header values in Angular 4 after redirect from java web app with response headers

Tags: angular

I have Java web application which will set header values in response.header("..","") and redirect  to Angular 4 app. How to read the header values in the Angular 4 in the constructor or oninit method.

Thanks,
Hari.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 4.3 HttpClient : Intercept response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45566944/angular-4-3-httpclient-intercept-response)