# Angular -Populate a list from a file(JSON/XML/CSV)

Tags: angular, typescript, service, populate

Context: Trying to build a CRUD app that reads a file from a given input field and then populates a list.

What I've done so far:

-service(products.service.ts):

```
 @Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ProductService {

  constructor(private http : HttpClient) { }

  private productsUrl= 'api/products';

  private handleError<T>(operation ='operation', result?: T){
    return (error: any): Observable<T> =>{
      console.log(error,'Operation : ${operation}');
      return of (result as T);
    }
  }      
  updateProduct(product: Product): Observable<any>{
      return this.http.put(this.productsUrl,product,httpOptions)
        .pipe(
          tap(_ => console.log(`Updated product of id ${product.id}!`)),
          catchError(this.handleError<any>('updateProduct'))
        )
    }

 addProduct(product: Product): Observable<Product> {
      return this.http.post<Product>(this.productsUrl, product, httpOptions).pipe(
        tap((product: Product) => console.log(`Added product with id ${product.id}!`)),
        catchError(this.handleError<Product>('addProduct'))
      );
    }
  (....)
}
```

I used in-memory-service-web-api to simulate a web api that has been used in my products.service.ts

Next up,comes the class that uses this service:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-products',
  templateUrl: './products.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./products.component.css']
})
export class ProductsComponent implements OnInit {

  products : Product[] ;

  selectedProduct :  Product;
  constructor(private productService : ProductService) { }

  onSelectProduct(product){
    this.selectedProduct = product;
    this.productService.getProduct(2)
      .subscribe(product =>console.log(product));
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getProducts();
  }
  save(product): void {
    this.productService.updateProduct(product)
      .subscribe(()=>console.log('Product saved!'))
  }
  add(name : string, price: number) : void {
    this.productService.addProduct({name,price} as Product)
      .subscribe(product =>{
        this.products.push(product);
      });
  }
(...)
    }
```

Also ,the template associated with that class:

```
(...)
<ul>
    <li 
    class="product" 
    [class.selected]="selectedProduct && selectedProduct.name === product.name"
    *ngFor="let product of products"
    >
        <input type="text" pInputText [(ngModel)]="product.name"/>
        <div (click)="onSelectProduct(product)">Name : {{product.name }}</div>
        <div>ID : {{product.id }}</div>
        <div>Price : {{product.price }}</div>
        <button (click)="save(product)" pButton type="button" label="Save" class="ui-button-success"></button>
        <button (click)="delete(product.id)" pButton type="button" label="Delete" class="ui-button-raised ui-button-danger"></button>
    </li>
  </ul>
(...)
```

As the title suggests ,I am trying to read from a file that can be of any format (not only JSON) and populate my list .How should I do this? I am trying to learn Angular and I'm stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can build an `HttpInterceptor` and check for content type so you can provide a different parse of the response ? Check this answer as it may help you : https://stackoverflow.com/a/51491994/3811645