# How to find out the circular reference from a complex array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, circular-reference

I am going to convert a array into a json string. However, when I convert it into json, a circular reference problem has been thrown. And the array is too complex that I can't find out the circular reference manually.

And I have tried the following function but it does not work

```
function isCyclic (obj) {
  var seenObjects = [];

  function detect (obj) {
    if (typeof obj === 'object') {
        if (seenObjects.indexOf(obj) !== -1) {
          return true;
        }
        seenObjects.push(obj);
        for (var key in obj) {
          if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key) && detect(obj[key])) {
            console.log(obj, 'cycle at ' + key);
            return true;
          }
        }
      }
      return false;
    }

  return detect(obj);
}
```

Does anyone has any other solution to find out the circular reference? Thanks~

Comment: What does your array contains ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Resolve circular references from JSON object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15312529/resolve-circular-references-from-json-object)