# Handling JSON References in Angular

Tags: json, angularjs

Let's say my API returns the following `people` array:

```
var p1 = new Person("Alice");
var p2 = new Person("Bob");
p1.Sibling = p2;
p2.Sibling = p1;
var people = new[] { p1, p2 };
```

To avoid circular references, it outputs the following JSON:

```
[  
   {  
      "$id":"1",
      "Name":"Alice",
      "Sibling":{  
         "$id":"2",
         "Name":"Bob",
         "Sibling":{  
            "$ref":"1"
         }
      }
   },
   {  
      "$ref":"2"
   }
]
```

However, Angular doesn't handle it. Instead, I end up with an array where the second object is just a literal object with a `$ref` property.

Googling around, I see Angular just doesn't support this, but I imagine there must be *some* way to get it working.

Comment: Sounds like your best bet is to run the result through an operation to resolve the references [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15312529/resolve-circular-references-from-json-object) has some relatively concise code snippets for doing that. The second answer has a few improvements compared to the first.

Comment: @charlietfl I assume $http could resolve any references before returning it in the promise. This is what many (non-javascript) JSON parsers do.

Comment: @JLRishe Thanks for the link.

Comment: alternative might be to copy objects at server to avoid circular references

Comment: @Pharylon, Is this issue of AngularJS or Chrome? We are trying the $ref method to reduce payload. Did you find any official links from Angular that they don't support the $ref? Could you please share any links?