# JSON with circular reference, @JsonIdentityInfo

Tags: javascript, java, json, spring-mvc, serialization

I am working with an object with multiple bi-directional reference, some of these references are deep within the object. I want to be able to serialize and deserialize this object. Once serialized, I want to be able to use the equivalent/serialized JSON using javascript(client side), and also be able to send this JSON back to the back end and have it deserialized correctly. I am using spring MVC for the back end.

I have tried [JSOG](https://github.com/jsog/jsog-jackson), works perfectly for serialization, but fails to deserialized.

I have also used

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class) 
public class A {
.
.
}
```

But the JSON received on the client side is unusable as it is, but has those `@id` fields.

Any one know of a JS library I can use to decode the received JSON at the client side when using `@JsonIdentityInfo` or any other better way around this?

Comment: I think you'll find the answer here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15312529/resolve-circular-references-from-json-object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15312529/resolve-circular-references-from-json-object)

Comment: please be more detailed, add the json you try to deserialize and more code...