# JSON.parse not recognizing string arrays

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, parsing

I try to read json content from a file, then parse and output it:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var data = fs.readFileSync(filename, 'utf8');
var json = JSON.parse(data);
console.log(json);
```

**Case 1**

JSON:

```
{
  "css": {
    "my.css": [
      "MyFolder/MyFile.less"
    ]
  }
}
```

Output:

```
{ css: { 'my.css': [ [Circular] ] } }
```

**Case 2**

JSON:

```
{
  "css": {
    "my.css": [
      "MyFolder/MyFile.less",
      "MyFolder/MyOtherFile.less"
    ]
  }
}
```

Output:

```
{ css: { 'my.css': [ 'MyFolder/MyFile.less', 'MyFolder/MyOtherFile.less' ] } }
```

Why do I get [Circular] in Case 1?

Comment: may be this would do http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15312529/resolve-circular-references-from-json-object

Comment: @Raja How does this help me? It's obvious that my json does not contain a reference, therefore a circular reference is not possible.

Comment: FWIW, I do not get this `Circular` -- using node 6.4.0 on mac.  Getting the expected result:  `{ css: { 'my.css': [ 'MyFolder/MyFile.less' ] } }`

Comment: By definition `JSON.parse` would not complain about circularity, so something is going on that you're not showing us.