# NHibernate json proxy serialization with with ReferencesAny

Tags: json, nhibernate

I have the following mapping:

```
    public class TimeLineEntityMap : BaseEntityMap<TimeLineEntity>
    {
        public TimeLineEntityMap()
        {
            Table("time_line_entity");
            Map(x => x.Message);
            Map(x => x.ResearchId, "research_id");//.Cascade.All().Not.LazyLoad();
            ReferencesAny(x => x.EntityRef)
                .AddMetaValue<EmailEntity>(typeof(EmailEntity).Name)
                .AddMetaValue<UrlEntity>(typeof(UrlEntity).Name)
                .AddMetaValue<PhoneEntity>(typeof(PhoneEntity).Name)
                .EntityTypeColumn("entity_type")
                .IdentityType<long>()
                .EntityIdentifierColumn("entity_ref_id")
                .Not.LazyLoad();
        }
    }
```

when fetching from the database `EntityRef` comes as a proxy.

```
TimeLineEntity res = timeLineRepository.Find(x => x.Id == id);
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(res);
```

the `JsonConvert` is throwing:

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Self referencing loop detected for property 'ManifestModule' with type 'System.Reflection.RuntimeModule'. Path 'Data[0].EntityRef._proxyFactoryInfo._getIdentifierMethod.Module.Assembly'.
```

this is my json settings:

```
     x.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
     x.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new NHibernateContractResolver();
```

```
    public class NHibernateContractResolver : CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver
    {
        protected override JsonContract CreateContract(Type objectType)
        {
            if (typeof(NHibernate.Proxy.INHibernateProxy).IsAssignableFrom(objectType))
                return base.CreateContract(objectType.BaseType);
            else
                return base.CreateContract(objectType);
        }
    }
```

Comment: So what is your problem?

Comment: @AmirChristian see the exception message

Comment: plz share your model class..

Comment: you need jsonignore

Answer (score 1):

Try to add [JsonIgnore] on your model class like this:

```
[JsonIgnore]
public class TimeLineEntity {

}
```

**UPDATE**
To get serialization of it You should resolve circular reference of map.

Below links will help you.(May be your answer already existed here.)

[JSON.NET Error Self referencing loop detected for type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7397207/json-net-error-self-referencing-loop-detected-for-type)

[Resolve circular references from JSON object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15312529/resolve-circular-references-from-json-object)

[Stringify (convert to JSON) a JavaScript object with circular reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10392293/stringify-convert-to-json-a-javascript-object-with-circular-reference)

http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/gilf/2011/10/17/avoiding-circular-reference-for-entity-in-json-serialization/

Good luck.

Comment: But i need this data to be serialized